# How do I add to the registry only if a property has been passed in via the command line?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

With the Wix install I would like my script to only update the registry if it has been passed parameters, current the installer will overwrite the existing entries regardless (putting in blanks if nothing is passed):

Currently I have this:

```
  <Component Id="RegistryEntries">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                 Key="Software\MyApplication\4"
          Action="create">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="doVersionCheck" Value="[VERSIONCHECK]" KeyPath="yes"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Country" Value="[COUNTRY]"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Address" Value="[ADDRESS]"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="language" Value="[LANGUAGE]"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Name" Value="[NAME]"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Organisation" Value="[ORGANISATION]"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="PostCode" Value="[POSTCODE]"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Email" Value="[EMAIL]"/>
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="largeUserControls" Value="[LARGEICONS]"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
```

Comment: Just add a condition to your component, e.g. `<Condition>UPDATE_REGISTRY</Condition>`

Comment: Per-User configuration data belongs in the application on first run not in the installer.  It takes a lot of Windows Installer understanding to pull it off correctly in WiX and that begins with knowing that MSI/WiX is *NOT* scripting.  PS- That is not a pedantic nitpick.  It's really important to understand what this means.

Comment: @Yan- There's more to it here.  The registry data is per-user so the component would also have to be transitive.  This also hints at property persistence issues.   There is much to consider and I think the best advice is to not try to do it in the installer and let the application own it via a first run / Tools | Options type pattern.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, that's a great comment, Chris! Totally agree